# spark 2.1.0 session config settings (pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to overwrite the spark session/spark context default configs, but it is picking entire node/cluster resource.

```
 spark  = SparkSession.builder
                      .master("ip")
                      .enableHiveSupport()
                      .getOrCreate()

 spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", '8g')
 spark.conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '3')
 spark.conf.set('spark.cores.max', '3')
 spark.conf.set("spark.driver.memory",'8g')
 sc = spark.sparkContext
```

It works fine when i put the configuration in spark submit

```
spark-submit --master ip --executor-cores=3 --diver 10G code.py
```

Comment: What is the resource manager ? Spark Standalone/YARN

Comment: Other way with 2.0 is `conf = (SparkConf().set("spark.executor.cores", "3"));  spark  = SparkSession.builder
                      .master("ip").conf(conf=conf)
                      .enableHiveSupport()
                      .getOrCreate()`

Comment: Sorry, tried both no luck. Can you try once. I just updated my spark to 2.2.0 snapshot to over come 64KB code size issue(SPARK-16845).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You aren't actually overwriting anything with this code. Just so you can see for yourself try the following.

As soon as you start pyspark shell type:

```
sc.getConf().getAll()
```

This will show you all of the current config settings. Then try your code and do it again. Nothing changes.

What you should do instead is create a new configuration and use that to create a SparkContext. Do it like this:

```
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '8g'), ('spark.executor.cores', '3'), ('spark.cores.max', '3'), ('spark.driver.memory','8g')])
sc.stop()
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Then you can check yourself just like above with:

```
sc.getConf().getAll()
```

This should reflect the configuration you wanted.

Comment: In spark 2.1.0/2.2.0 we can define sc = pyspark.SparkContext like this. No option to pass the parameter.

Comment: Are you saying its not possible to pass it in? The docs still have it listed as an argument, see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext)

Comment: [See here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql]  . i am not clear what is the entry point now?

Comment: If you are referring to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sparkContext) line, that refers to checking the existing spark context object. So for example when you start pyspark the sparkcontext already exists as sc. Typing `sc` is essentially equal to typing `SparkSession.SparkContext` and returns the current context object. My understanding is that you want to create a context with a different configuration.

Comment: I have done small chnages and it worked ..Thank you.. `spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf1).getOrCreate()`    `sc = spark.sparkContext` here conf1 is what you defined above (conf = **)

Comment: It is a bug [refer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19307​)

Comment: I am finding it is ignoring the SparkContext settings (PYTHONPATH) for example. Any known issues with SparkSession not picking these up? I can see the settings there.

Comment: @Grr can you please update the answer so it works with 2.3.1 ?

Comment: Can't we setup config before spark start ??

Comment: @mithril Absolutely, and i would always do so. But the question was about changing the config after the fact.

Answer (score 44):

update configuration in **Spark 2.3.1**

To change the default spark configurations you can follow these steps:

**Import the required classes**

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

**Get the default configurations**

```
spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()
```

**Update the default configurations**

```
conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '4g'), ('spark.app.name', 'Spark Updated Conf'), ('spark.executor.cores', '4'), ('spark.cores.max', '4'), ('spark.driver.memory','4g')])
```

**Stop the current Spark Session**

```
spark.sparkContext.stop()
```

**Create a Spark Session**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Also works with 2.2.0.  Thanks for providing this answer.

Comment: I have used `spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '4g'), ...])` without recreating the session (meaning I did not use your two last steps). When I take a look at the config afterwards (`spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()`) I also see the set parameters. However, I'm not sure if I just overwrote the object just saving the config within the `sparkConf`..

Comment: @Markus: you can check the configurations in Spark UI

Comment: you are using varaible 'spark' in conf and then using 'conf' variable in spark lol.
how can i change the spark configuration once i start the session??

Comment: @imran: u need to stop the session and start it again. In code, spark variable is reassigned with new spark session using updated conf.

Comment: Anyone could make this work when launching spark-submit in cluster mode?? I am only able to stop and restart sparkContext when running in client mode...

Comment: @Markus, you overwrote an entry in spark.sparkContext._conf object, however that did affect he real properties of your spark object. The real properties of your SparkSession object are the ones you pass to object's constructor.

Comment: This will **not** update the ```spark.driver.memory```. See this answer for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606756/how-to-set-spark-driver-memory-in-client-mode-pyspark-version-2-3-1/62799033#62799033

Comment: @bob After reconfiguring my spark `conf` as you suggested, when I execute the SparkSession builder, iI get an error saying that `Promise already completed`. Any idea how to overcome that?

Comment: Doesn't work for me: just broke Pyspark session and every cell now returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setJobGroup'` error :(

Answer (score 4):

Setting 'spark.driver.host' to 'localhost' in the config works for me

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.driver.host", "localhost") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also set configuration when you start pyspark, just like spark-submit:

```
pyspark --conf property=value
```

Here is one example

```html
-bash-4.2$ pyspark
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019, 21:02:35) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0-cdh6.2.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019 21:02:35)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> spark.conf.get('spark.eventLog.enabled')
'true'
>>> exit()


-bash-4.2$ pyspark --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019, 21:02:35) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0-cdh6.2.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019 21:02:35)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> spark.conf.get('spark.eventLog.enabled')
'false'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very different requirement where I had to check if I am getting parameters of executor and driver memory size and if getting, had to replace config with only changes in executer and driver. Below are the steps:

1. Import Libraries

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

2. Define Spark and get the default configuration

```
spark = (SparkSession.builder
        .master("yarn")
        .appName("experiment") 
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.multiobjectdelete.enable", "false")
        .getOrCreate())

conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()
```

3. Check if executor and driver size exists (I am giving here pseudo code 1 conditional check, rest you can create cases) then use the given configuration based on params or skip to the default configuration.

```
if executor_mem is not None and driver_mem  is not None:
    conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.executor.memory',executor_mem),('spark.driver.memory',driver_mem)])
    spark.sparkContext.stop()
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
else:
    spark = spark
```

Don't forget to stop spark context, this will make sure executor and driver memory size have differed as you passed in params. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is little old post and have some already accepted ans, but I just wanted to post a working code for the same.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.driver.host", "localhost") \
    .getOrCreate()

default_conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()
print(default_conf)

conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '4g'),
                                        ('spark.app.name', 'Spark Updated Conf'),
                                        ('spark.executor.cores', '4'),
                                        ('spark.cores.max', '4'),
                                        ('spark.driver.memory','4g')])

spark.sparkContext.stop()

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config(conf=conf) \
    .getOrCreate()


default_conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.get("spark.cores.max")
print("updated configs " , default_conf)
```