# Spring Boot + neo4j; Unsupported authentication token, scheme 'none' is only allowed when auth is disabled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j

I'm trying to connect with neo4j from Java Spring Boot application. Neo4J is started as Docker image in docker compose file.

I receive following error:

> 2023-06-22T14:37:36.821+02:00 ERROR 1164 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed:
> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
> open a new Neo4j session: Unsupported authentication token, scheme
> 'none' is only allowed when auth is disabled.] with root cause
>
> org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Unsupported
> authentication token, scheme 'none' is only allowed when auth is
> disabled.

File **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:4.1.9
    container_name: neo4j-container
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
```

File **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-springboot-helloworld-db-nosql-neo4j-crud</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        
        <!-- DB dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

File **application.yaml**:

```
spring:
  data:
    neo4j:
      uri: bolt://localhost
      username: neo4j
      password: password
```

I have checked and the credentials I am passing are correct. Not sure why is it failing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58377865/unsupported-authentication-token-scheme-none-only-allowed-when-auth-is-disabl

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by updating **application.yaml** file:

```
spring:
  neo4j:
    uri: bolt://localhost:7687
    authentication:
      username: neo4j
      password: password
```

It seems that for Spring Boot 3 properties were changed.

Working example of Spring Boot 3 with Neo4J you can find here: https://github.com/wisniewskikr/chrisblog-it-java-springboot/tree/main/others/db/no-sql/java-springboot-helloworld-db-nosql-neo4j-crud